# Auto update in Motorola i465 and i416 j2me

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, symbian

I'm developing a j2me application to Motorola i465 and i416, but i need to do the application to auto update. I followed this tutorial http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/updatingjavame-1420213.html and the code works fine, however, apparently my carrier has blocked this function.

Here is my code:

```
protected void startApp() {
    //Update app      
    try {
      this.platformRequest("http://s3.amazonaws.com/pontonextel/Pontotel.jad");
      System.out.println("Update");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

and the .JAD content:

```
MIDlet-Jar-Size: 33305
MIDlet-1: Pontotel,,Pontotel
MIDlet-Jar-URL: http://s3.amazonaws.com/pontonextel/Pontotel.jar
MIDlet-Icon: 
MIDlet-Delete-Notify: 
MIDlet-Version: 5.0.0
MIDlet-Install-Notify: 
MIDlet-Vendor: Lar21
MIDlet-Description: 
MIDlet-Name: Pontotel
```

In emulator is ok but in both devices is opened the default web browser and is shown the error message "The requested Page can not be displayed".

Anyone can help me to unblock these devices or a other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.com

Some/most phones requires the server to have the correct MIME-types for JAR and JAD files before the phone-browser accepts them.

MIME-type for JAD:
text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor

MIME-type for JAR:
application/java-archive

Try setting these up on the server.

Note: Some servers requires you to wait a little while after adding MIME-types before they're in effect.

Comment: I've done this, but the problem remains. Other suggestions?

Comment: That should do it. Are you absolutely sure that you added the MIME types correctly? Are you sure that the device is actually online? Some phones have two different internet settings; one for phone and one for j2me. Try the URL in the phone browser too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your attention =D. I'm sure that the MIME types are correctly and in the browser is same error.

Comment: Try this URL, just to test. Does this work on your phone? http://piratediamonds.com/mobile/ota.php?h=320
Also, please add the content of your JAD file in your question above.

Comment: Hm, ok, it's definitely your carrier that's the problem. Your URL works fine  on my Sony Ericsson Aino. I'd say your carrier might even have a bug somewhere. I can't spot anything wrong with your files nor setup. Try contacting your carrier. The only time I experienced this myself, where one carrier refused to accept the URL while another worked fine, it was the missing MIME-type that fixed it.

Comment: Do you know if the device is jailbroken?

Comment: Feature phones aren't jailbroken. Only iPhones are jailbroken and Android devices are rooted. Sony Ericsson feature phones can be hacked though, e.g. to remove the JavaME security. But I haven't done this with my Aino.
The problem you're having lies with your carrier. I bet if you try another simcard from another carrier in your Motorola phone, then everything works fine. Try it.

Comment: i need use this simcard.

Answer (score 0):

Motorola feature phones use an iDEN Open Java Application Loader to enable them to install j2me applications. There is also a known issue where the jad attribute MIDlet-Jar-Size  value is not defined or different from the real jar size and it blocks the installation. Please check it out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but isn't it. My .jad is generated by Motorola iDEN SDK and the .jad works in another devices. And my objective is install application via OTA (Over the Air)